# pymongo - Very slow to iterate on cursor

Tags: python, pymongo

I am currently writing a python program to analyse cryptocurrency data stored in a mongo database.
The speed to get the data from the database to my cursor is fairly quick, but my biggest problem is when I iterate the cursor itself. I take 7 seconds to start doing operations on it. My function is used a lot in my program and waiting 7 seconds for each call isn't great for short time analysis.

This is the code of my function

```
def startDateForNewUpdateKlines(coin):
    lastKlines = db.candlestick1m.find({"symbol": coin}).sort("close_time", pymongo.DESCENDING).limit(1)
    lastDate = -1
    print("Processing Klines")
    for kline in lastKlines:
        print("performance test")
        if kline['close_time'] >= lastDate:
            lastDate = kline['close_time']
    # If the coin is not in DB yet, starting date will be  01/01/2018
    if (lastDate == -1):
        return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1514761200000 / 1000.0).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp((lastDate + 1) / 1000.0).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

As you can see, my cursor only contains one element, and my tests concluded that what take a long time is the line

```
for kline in lastKlines:
```

It take 7 seconds from showing "Processing Klines" to showing "performance test"

I also tried writing

```
lastKlines = list(db.candlestick1m.find({"symbol": coin}).sort("close_time", pymongo.DESCENDING).limit(1))
```

Now, that line also take about 7 seconds to complete.

I am currently using python 2.7.14 (the librairy I use is only available in 2.7 and i would really like not converting it myself to 3.6.4 ) and pymongo 3.6.1

I am open to any suggestion to finally fix this performance problem.

Comment: Can you try commenting out the performance test print statement? If there are a lot of klines, the print statement can bottleneck performance.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a problem with slow iteration; that sounds like you've misunderstood exactly when the results get computed and transferred to Python.

Comment: @castle-bravo : My cursor containing only one element (limit(1)), the printing only occurs one.
*@user2357112 : What do you mean exactly ?

Comment: You seem to think the query is done and all results are transferred once you call `db.candlestick1m.find({"symbol": coin}).sort("close_time", pymongo.DESCENDING).limit(1)`. It looks more like that only sets up the query, without running it.

Comment: The sort could be slow on a very large collection. Have you tried timing it directly in the mongo console? Also, if it's mongo, try indexing either the "symbol" or "close_time" (or an index on both).

Comment: You are right, the problem comes from the 'sort' of my query that takes very long to execute (about 6 seconds in mongo console). I will try the indexing and will tell you my results

Comment: Ok. I did my index on the "symbol" and it reduced my query time from 6011 ms to 608 ms. Thank you very much !